# Exception while invoking method 'Mongol_verifyDoc' ReferenceError: Match is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am new to meteor don't know why i am getting this error in console.

```
=> Meteor server restarted                    
I20160127-14:34:59.949(5.5)? Exception while invoking method 'Mongol_verifyDoc' ReferenceError: Match is not defined
I20160127-14:34:59.949(5.5)?     at [object Object].Meteor.(anonymous function).Mongol_verifyDoc (packages/msavin_jetsetter/server/main.js:1:1)
I20160127-14:34:59.950(5.5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1698:12)
I20160127-14:34:59.950(5.5)?     at livedata_server.js:708:19
I20160127-14:34:59.950(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160127-14:34:59.950(5.5)?     at livedata_server.js:706:40
I20160127-14:34:59.950(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160127-14:34:59.950(5.5)?     at livedata_server.js:704:46
I20160127-14:34:59.950(5.5)?     at tryCallTwo (/home/sachin/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.5.1.1550ocw++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
I20160127-14:34:59.950(5.5)?     at doResolve (/home/sachin/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.5.1.1550ocw++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:171:13)
I20160127-14:34:59.950(5.5)?     at new Promise (/home/sachin/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.5.1.1550ocw++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:65:3)
```

I am using following packages:-

```
meteor-base             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifiers      # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
es5-shim                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
erasaur:meteor-lodash
stolinski:stylus-multi
fortawesome:fontawesome
spiderable
fastclick
raix:handlebar-helpers
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
accounts-ui
accounts-password
matb33:bootstrap-glyphicons
msavin:jetsetter
zimme:active-route
gwendall:auth-client-callbacks
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvkQNTIfbQk

I had the same error as well
There's a comment that says to run

```
meteor add check
```

This resolved the error for me

Comment: Actually the better answer is probably this:
Replace the jetsetter package with meteortoys:allthings
This is highlighted in one of the later videos in the series

Answer (score 1):

Just comment out the following package from your `.meteor/local/packages` file.

```
msavin:jetsetter
```